# Analysing data in list of objects

Tags: python, object, youtube, analyzer

I am attempting to analyse data from multiple YouTube videos.  I have no idea how to use the YouTube API or even if it's possible via that method.  Instead I am using Python 2.7 through PythonAnywhere.

I have created a 'Video' class with many attributes:

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self, title, description, views, likes, dislikes, tags, comments...):
        self.title = title
        ...
```

and have scraped this data for thousands of videos.  The plan is to analyse the data to find out the average number of views, likes etc. and the most popular words in titles, descriptions... or the video with the most views per day (based on upload date and current views).  There are many things I am attempting to analyse.

The question is: What is the best way to analyse this type of data for a list of many objects?  (or is there a better way rather than using a list of objects?)

I have attempted this through a single `for` loop that accumulates figures, then I display the figures at the end.

I have also attempted using list comprehensions (for example `print("Longest title:" + str(max([len(v.title) for v in allVids])))`.

I'm worried that using multiple list comprehensions like this is inefficient and that a single, giant `for` loop is better in the long run, if not for readability.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I apologise for such a broad question; I couldn't find an answer elsewhere on this site.

**Edit - More information:**
I'm scraping the data from the top ten trending videos at the same time each day.  The list of objects for a single day is being saved as a pickle file.  When analysing the data, I've been loading all of the files and adding them all to a single list.

The reason I'm looking for the most/more efficient way is because I'm using PythonAnywhere to schedule the scraping of the data and I don't want to be in the tarpit all the time; I need some processing time to analyse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a good case for a Pandas data frame to me where each video's stats would be a column or row with the related data.

You would probably need to do a for loop to build the data frame initially but assuming it fits in memory you should be pretty set for the rest of your evaluations. It would look something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['upload date', 'title', 'description', 'views', 'likes', 'dislikes']

# add data to data frame
for vid in saved_vids:
    df[vid, 'title'] = vid.title
    df[vid, 'views'] = vid.views
    # and so on
```

This would easily allow you to find average views per day, likes, etc.

```
df.views.mean()
```

Look into indexes and selections for subsetting options and filtering.

You may have to do something different with the comments depending on how you want to analyse them, but I think that pandas would offer you a good basis to evaluate things you might like to see. If you loaded all comments into a data frame you could use the str.contains operators to find things. I haven't done too much with that though so there may be a better way.

Comment: Using Pandas seems to be a much neater way of doing many of the required analyses.  Like you say, comments are trickier and there are certain things (such as the percentage of titles that are proper-case) that may require a different approach, but Pandas definitely cleaned up a lot of mess and reduced a lot of looping.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I do know it is pretty easy to do case insensitive stuff with pandas by taking a whole columns of text as lower or upper case. May help you with you proper-case titles. IE: df.titles.str.lower().isin(['cool title 1', 'cool title 2'])

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each Video instance holds the attributes of one video, then each time you create a new Video instance you could update a global variable. Something like:

```
total_views += video.views
```

or:

```
if video.views > most_viewed_video.views:
    most_viewed_video = video
```

This is a fairly straight forward and simple approach without knowing anything else about your code base. Theoretically, you should be able to get rid of the for loop entirely, unless you want to compare a select number a videos against each other.

Comment: I like that suggestion but I am scraping data on a daily basis and the objects are saved in a pickle file, so it's too late to implement this (though I could run a one-off script that adds up these running totals and then add code to the objects to update as and when they are scraped - I might look into that).